# Oracle rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with following columns and 2 rows :

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,NAME,DATE
```

Value of COL1,COL2,COL3 in both rows are A,B,C. Value of NAME in 1st row is 'DEL' and 2nd row is 'LAP'. Value of DATE in 1st row is '11.12.13' and 2nd row is '13.11.13'.

Now i want a view with singlerow and following columns

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,DEL,LAP with values A,B,C,11.12.13,13.11.13.
```

Is that possible with pivot or any other function

thanks

Comment: Hi...can you pls tell the metjhod for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21abc/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (COL1,COL2,COL3,N_NAME,D_DATE) AS 
          SELECT  'A','B','C', 'DEL', '11.12.13' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  'A','B','C', 'LAP', '13.11.13' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  'A','B','C', 'DEL', '12.12.13' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  'A','B','C', 'LAP', '14.11.13' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If the combination of `COL1`, `COL2`, `COL3` and `N_Name` is unique then you can do:

```
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3,
       MIN( CASE N_Name WHEN 'DEL' THEN D_Date END ) AS DEL,
       MIN( CASE N_Name WHEN 'LAP' THEN D_Date END ) AS LAP
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21abc/3/0)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |      DEL |      LAP |
|------|------|------|----------|----------|
|    A |    B |    C | 11.12.13 | 13.11.13 |
```

**Query 2**:

However, if you can have multiple rows with the same combination of `COL1`, `COL2`, `COL3` and `N_Name` and you want all of them returning (in date order) then you can do:

```
WITH indexed_data AS (
  SELECT Col1,
         Col2,
         Col3,
         N_Name,
         D_Date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Col3, N_Name ORDER BY D_Date ) AS idx
  FROM   table_name  
)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3,
       MIN( CASE N_Name WHEN 'DEL' THEN D_Date END ) AS DEL,
       MIN( CASE N_Name WHEN 'LAP' THEN D_Date END ) AS LAP
FROM   indexed_data
GROUP BY
       Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3,
       idx
ORDER BY
       Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3,
       idx
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21abc/3/1)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |      DEL |      LAP |
|------|------|------|----------|----------|
|    A |    B |    C | 11.12.13 | 13.11.13 |
|    A |    B |    C | 12.12.13 | 14.11.13 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with tab (COL1,COL2,COL3,N_NAME,D_DATE) as ( 
select  'A','B','C', 'DEL', '11.12.13' from dual union all
select  'A','B','C', 'LAP', '13.11.13' from dual)
select COL1, COL2, COL3, 
       min(decode(N_NAME, 'DEL', D_DATE, NULL)) DEL,
       min(DECODE(N_NAME, 'LAP', D_DATE, NULL)) LAP
from tab
group by COL1, COL2, COL3
```

output

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |      DEL |      LAP |
|------|------|------|----------|----------|
|    A |    B |    C | 11.12.13 | 13.11.13 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the common fields in both rows are COL1, COL2 and COL3.

```
SELECT a.col1, 
       a.col2, 
       a.col3, 
       a.date AS DEL, 
       b.date AS LAP 
FROM   yourtable AS a 
       INNER JOIN yourtable AS b 
               ON a.col1 = b.col1 
                  AND a.col2 = b.col2 
                  AND a.col3 = b.col3 
                  AND a.name = 'DEL' 
                  AND b.name = 'LAP'
```